# Turning off net.sf.ehcache and org.hibernate DEBUG logging

Tags: spring, ehcache

I am getting a host of DEBUG messages from `net.sf.ehcache` and `org.hibernate` in my Spring (version 5.2.5.RELEASE) application.  I am using version 5.2.10.Final of `hibernate-ehcache`.  The messages look like this:

```
16:20:12.910 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.statistics.extended.ExtendedStatisticsImpl - Mocking Operation Statistic: XA_COMMIT
16:20:12.910 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.statistics.extended.ExtendedStatisticsImpl - Mocking Operation Statistic: XA_ROLLBACK
16:20:12.910 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.statistics.extended.ExtendedStatisticsImpl - Mocking Operation Statistic: XA_RECOVERY
```

and also many like this:

```
1:14:39.284 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity [com.acme.MyBean#145]
```

I've tried to turn them down by using this in log4j.xml

```
<logger name="net.sf.ehcache">
    <level value="WARN"/>
</logger>
```

I've also tried this in application.properties:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=WARNING
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
logging.level.org.springframework.cache=WARNING
```

But neither of these changes filters out the DEBUG messages.

Here is the ehcache configuration as defined in spring-config.xml:

```
<bean id="readOnlyDatabaseSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.debug}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.debug}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">${hibernate.debug}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">
                org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
            </prop>
            <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">
                ehcache.xml
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">100</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="readOnlyDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

I have the following settings in application.properties:

```
# logging for hibernate
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=warn
logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=warn
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=warn

logging.level.org.springframework.web=WARN
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
logging.level.org.springframework.cache=WARN

logging.level.root=WARN
logging.level.net.sf.ehcache=WARN

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=false
```

How do I turn off DEBUG messages for `net.sf.ehcache` and `org.hibernate`?

Comment: can you share configurations, is Ehcache is 2nd level cache?

Comment: or sample github project would be awesome.: application.properties I have played with: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties

Comment: I added ehcache information.  Is that what you wanted to know?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn off the logging on a specific package you should use the value `off`. This will work both on package and class level like:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=OFF

com.yourproject.util.SomeUtilsClass=OFF
```

Normally `logging.level.net.sf.ehcache=WARN` should work, but can you try:

```
logging.level.net.sf.ehcache.statistics.extended=WARN
```

If you're running a junit test you should update/create different config for that because by default junit will use `DEBUG` as the root log level where when you launch your springboot app it will use by default `INFO` and what you customized in your application.properties.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome in the world of Open Source where you have many options to choose from, but documentation is scarce.

I don't know whether you use only Spring or also Spring Boot, how you start your application, and without having a reproducable scenario it is impossible to give a precise answer so here comes a bit longer and more complex answer:

1. application.properties might work if you use the right logging libraries (e.g. in pom.xml ) and the right way to initialize spring boot (which you probably don't use)
2. if you are sure that you use spring boot (dependencies + initialization) but your configuration files are ignored although the application is reading them it may be that you override the settings using e.g.: environment variables, see [the 17 different ways to externalize configuration for spring boot 1.2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.5.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)
3. if you use maven you may want to get a clearer picture of which logging frameworks you use by executing some of these commands: `mvn dependency:tree` or `mvn help:effective-pom` or in any case look at the Java classpath for which files and directories your logging libraries and configuration files might be loaded from and read their respective documentation on how to configure them (which is very different e.g. for the non-backwards compatible log4j2 than for log4j 1.x, logback, etc.)
4. before you start pulling your hair in desperation because you really cannot find where your application tries to load logging configuration from, run a tracing tool for your operating system to see which files it opens and reads during startup, e.g.: strace (Linux), sysinternals process monitor (Windows) offer insight into the interaction between your application (Java) and the operating system

Finally, be aware that some logging frameworks (e.g.: log4j2, slf4j) have been split in multiple parts, e.g.:

1. for the programmer to program/compile against
2. for the runtime to write the logging to a file, over the network or to another logging framework
3. integration to also receive logging from other framworks

See for some great examples how you can use that:

- for Log4j2 [this documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/faq.html)
- for SLF4J/logback [that documentation](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html)